# How to use Ajax to bring a page into my site then wait until it is fully loaded scripts and all

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a site which pulls pages into a dynamic interface. Currently, the main page requires that any javascript the external pages will need be loaded with the main page. Most javascript  the external pages have are objects that are built when the page gets pulled in, but first, which causes issues.

It's a little hard for me to explain for some reason so here's a simple walk through of process.

1.Request a page be pulled in

2.Based on a variable passed to function create a specific object which will be associated with the physical html coming from the page ( This is the external Javascript)

3.Load page into the objects frame

This flow requires that the external javascript be attached to the main page not the page being pulled in.

I want to switch steps 2 and 3, but I assume that I will need a way to know that the page and all its scripts have fully loaded before attempting to create the designated object, but I have no idea how to do that.

I am using jQuery and hope that this can be accomplished without a plugin but if it is needed then so be it.

Thanks

**Update**

Good questions. So the pages are local pages that we build at this point, so we know what to expect. Also the pages are loaded just into basic div structure.

Specifically the main page makes a request to get a page. That page is returned in the form of a string and is then pasted into a div element that is on the main page. The pages are more like fragments I guess. But they can range from fairly complicated and require a bit of javascript to not using any javascript at all.

And the external javascript would generally be added via a script tag and is not inline.

**Due to the dynamic nature of the page we do NOT use IFRAME's, they cause issues with the movement of our modules.**

Comment: Is the external js embedded in the page using a script to include it, or is it inline js (ie `<script src="test.js"></script>` vs `<script type="text/javascript">some js</script>`)

Comment: Can you give some more details of your implementation, specifically how are these external pages being pulled in and to what extent? Is it an iframe? Do you control the external pages markup or no? Do you know  reliably what to expect the external pages to look like if not or could they be any HTML doc?

Comment: Did you try to load your page with an IFRAME, and set an `onload` event to it, to trigger the import to the parent page?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an iframe then I imagine you are changing it's src attribute. To get an alert on when that iframe is done loading you should include a script on the page within the iframe:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        alert("All Done");
    });
</script>
```

If you are just requesting a string version of a page via AJAX and populating a div you need some extra JavaScript to detect when those dynamically loaded script files have finished downloading to the client.

I would visit this [link](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/109) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of Nick and Mic's solution.

In your IFRAME pages, you need a way to determine when the content is done loading, or ready, and then alert your main page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        parent.frameReady();
    });
</script>
```

In your main page, you can code in the hook from your IFRAMEs:

```
<script>
    function frameReady() {
        // attach custom js to iframe here
    }
</script>
```